# Remove character from string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a data frame as given below:

```
data$Latitude
"+28.666428" "+28.666470" "+28.666376" "+28.666441" "+28.666330" "+28.666391"

str(data$Latitude)
Factor w/ 1368 levels "+10.037451","+10.037457",..
```

I want to remove the "+" character from each of the Latitude values.
I tried using `gsub()`

```
data$Latitude<-gsub("+","",as.character(factor(data$Latitude)))
```

This isn't working.

Comment: add `fixed = TRUE` in `gsub`, or escape it `\\+`

Comment: Or just `as.numeric(as.character("+28.666428"))`.

Comment: @Sotos: Thanks buddy..that worked.. also the reply was quick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `sapply`, `substring` and `regexpr` to achieve the result.
`regexpr(<character>,<vector>)[1]` gives you the index of the character.
Using the value as the start index for `substring`, the rest of the string can be separated.
`sapply` allows you loop through the values.

Here is the data.

```
d<-c("+28.666428","+28.666470","+28.666376","+28.666441","+28.666330")
```

Here is the logic.

```
v <- sapply(d, FUN = function(d){substring(d, regexpr('+',d) + 1, nchar(d))}, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Here is the output

```
> v
[1] "28.666428" "28.666470" "28.666376" "28.666441" "28.666330" "28.666391"
```

Comment: `regexpr('+', d)` doesn’t do what you think it does (try it with `d = 'foo'`) — I’m not exactly sure why R accepts this at all, since it’s an invalid regular expression, and it should throw an error. Furthermore, this solution is extremely convoluted. `gsub` works just as well.